# Docker container is not loading wwwroot content Dotnet Core 3.1

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I have a Layered based application including API, Business, Common, Domain and Infrastructure layers.
API layer has a wwwroot folder which includes Angular build content.

In startup, where the pipeline is configured, I enabled UseStaticFiles().

[image]

When I run locally, using

> donet watch run

the application runs successfully.

Next, I build docker file. The docker file is placed in a directory where .sln is located.

[image]

Here is the content of the docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln /build/
COPY Admin.Core/*.csproj ./build/Admin.Core/
COPY Admin.Business.Common/*.csproj ./build/Admin.Business.Common/
COPY Admin.Infrastructure/*.csproj ./build/Admin.Infrastructure/
COPY Admin.Business/*.csproj ./build/Admin.Business/
COPY Admin.API/*.csproj ./build/Admin.API/

# COPY *.csproj /build/
RUN dotnet restore ./build/Admin.API/Admin.API.csproj

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./build/

WORKDIR /build
RUN dotnet publish ./Admin.API/Admin.API.csproj -c Release -o out 

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Admin.API.dll"]
```

When I build an image and run in the container, the application runs successful, and I can make a successful call to API using postman. but in browser, wwwroot content is not loaded.
The folder exists in the container files.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a docker issue. This is incorrect usage of the middleware in .NET Core.

Static Files should be added before the routing.

```
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    .
    .
    .
    app.UseRouting();
```

The order in which middleware are added is extremely important. Because `UseRouting` is added before `UseStaticFiles` it's the MVC routing that is looking for the images and css files for a matching MVC rule, which of course isn't available. And hence those are probably not found.

Changing the order will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually I did this yesterday. 
But results are still  the same.

Comment: @arslanMunir Did you solve it? plz tell me I am having the same issue ;(

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that paths in docker containers (backed by Linux?) are case sensitive. So changing the file/project names to be all lowercase could solve the issue. I have never tested this, however.